# How to disable auto-update for virtual machines in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, auto-update

In my azure environment there are sets of virtual machines that are rebooting at the same time, I assume it has to do with auto-update settings. How do I turn off the auto-updates and enable manual scheduling for Azure Virtual Machine updates? When I go to the update blade it doesn't provide me any options.

Comment: FYI this belongs on ServerFault, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey @JohnFisher had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely disable the automatic updates for virtual machines in Azure by opting out of the **‘Automatic upgrades’** option in the Virtual machine’s **‘Operations’** section --> **Update Management** workspace as shown in the below snapshot. Same is the case for **‘Automatic updates’** for *Guest OS* and *Host OS* also because, if the *‘Update Management’* option is **enabled**, then **an automation and a log analytics workspace account is created as shown below due to which the update management schedule for the Guest as well as Host OS is managed through the ‘Update Management’** section as the status of the VM’s update is reported in it through backend automation account and a log analytics workspace: -

[image: VM Update management]
[image: Update Management section]
[image: Update Management Automation]

Thus, to disable the automatic updates for your VMs for the above option, i.e., through ‘Update Management’ feature, kindly refer to the below documentation link for details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/remove-feature

•   Basically, when you provision a VM in Azure, at that time itself, you are asked the option for **‘Automatic by OS’** updates or **‘Manual’ updates** in the **‘Patch Orchestration’ option under ‘Management’ section**. At that time, if you select, ‘Automatic by OS’, then the updates for the VM are **configured to be installed automatically** in the VM’s OS registry and accordingly whenever the updates are available, the VM’s OS installs the updates regularly. But, for manual updates option, the **updates aren’t installed until the user who has logged in to the VM installs them**. Thus, to disable the automatic update feature from within the VM, kindly follow the steps below: -

a)  Go to **Control Panel** --> **Administrative Tools** --> **Services**

b)  Scroll down to **‘Windows Update’** in the resulting list

c)  Double click the **‘Windows Update’** Entry

d)  In the resulting dialog, if the service is started, click **'Stop'**

e)  Set **‘Startup Type’** to **‘Disabled’**

Kindly note the consequences of the above actions: -

If you disable Windows 10 Updates, your system will be at risk from attack and

a)  Windows Defender will not be updated.

b)  Operating System patches will not be applied.

c)  You will not be able to use the Windows Store.

d)  Windows Apps will not update and possibly fail.

e)  On the plus side your hardware will continue to work.